# Why do I need two AAD applications just to add roles into an access token?

Tags: azure-active-directory

As shown by many samples I have two AAD application registrations, one for my javascript-based front end, and one for my JSON-only web APIs.

If I fully trust my client AAD application, why does AAD require me to create a second AAD application for my web APIs?

For example, assuming I add specific roles to my client AAD application, if client signs in with AAD and gets an id token and access token containing my roles, it only needs to send the access token to my APIs. The API only needs to crack the JWT, validate the audience, issuer, tenant, roles permissions, and signature. In this world, no client secret is needed in the web APIs, a second AAD application registration not needed, and still no call to AAD from my APIs. Unfortunately, without two AAD applications, I cannot figure out a way to have AAD include roles into my access token.

If I didn't fully trust the issuer from mucking with claims, I can see why I would need two AAD applications and a client secret. But since I do trust my AAD application and the signature of the JWT, why the extra complexity? Or maybe there is a way to do this that I haven't found?

Thanks!

---

Responding to Marc here because just not enough characters in the comments field -- [The sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code) you referenced is an excellent sample, specifically the [JavaScript one calling the Web API](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi-v2). It is what I am doing right now in fact. However, the problem is that Web API in the sample is open to anybody who has authenticated on the tenant. I need to secure the Web API down to certain individuals in the tenant, and simply checking the client/app id is not sufficient as [anybody who can create an AAD app can fake it](https://joonasw.net/view/always-check-token-permissions-in-aad-protected-api).

So what I need to do is have roles added to the the access token so I know that my application authenticated the user, and that user has been granted the required roles. For example, here is a [Microsoft sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/). And even [here](https://youtu.be/V8VUPixLSiM?t=1875) a Microsoft video walking through the process.

If I don't have two AAD applications w/client secret, the roles claims is never provided in the access token. It is always provided in the id token, but not the access token.

I feel like I am missing something obvious here. If AAD would just put the roles I requested into the JWT when I authenticated against it, and I validated its signature, audience, issuer, and roles, I wouldn't need any of this extra complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I think I understand where you are going: you would like to control which users can access an API, no matter what client app they are using to access the API with. That's a function of the API - you cannot control that through AAD. In AAD you can control which users can access which applications (UI) using either user access restrictions (enterprise tab) or role-based access. However, access to an **API** is controlled in AAD at **the calling application level** via scopes. APIs are never accessed directly by users but only by other apps so controlling access permissions at user level would cause admin havoc. So, you can control what permissions a user has in the app they are using and you can control what permissions that application (client) has in other applications (APIs, resource servers) it is using.

In other words: role is about user access to UI, scope is about one apps' access to another.

App secrets provide added security for getting tokens - they have no bearing on what permissions are included in the token.

Comment: Correction and apologies. You can define user roles for an API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/app-roles) and assign users to these roles through the Enterprise Tab. If your client app then asks for a user delegated token, AAD will return an access token to the API which includes both the requested scopes plus AND a role claim with user roles as assigned to this user. Your API will need to use both scopes and role claim for its authorization. Sorry for saying earlier AAD ignores roles defined for an API.

Comment: Your client can ask for just the user_impersonation scope (an API always has it even if not explicitly defined). The access token will then have just this one scope and user roles.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a link showing that two apps are needed? That should only be the case if the API you want to call is not provided by the web app which served the JS to the browser. None of the ['official' samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code) require you to register two apps (Graph API, used in some of these samples is a separate API and it is already registered). A problem with tokens passed from the browser is that they were acquired by a public client, not using any secrets apart from user creds. Therefore, they are easier to steal and re-use. Your own back-end app may want to use a secret to get its own token (extension grant) to call yet another API using a token that does not reside in a public client.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I replied in my original question above because the comments field didn't provide enough characters.